# Combining points that are close in space and time using R

Tags: r, sf

I have table of data that contain 5 columns:

Unique_ID, Date_time, Lat, Long, Incident_Count

The sensors that supply this data often take what should be one occurrence, and split it up into several. eg I have three rows that look like this:

```
Unique_ID, Date_time, Lat, Long, Incident Count
xxx, 12/4/19 10:01, xxx, xxx, 2
xxx, 12/4/19 10:02, xxx, xxx, 4
xxx, 12/4/19 10:02,xxx, xxx, 3
```

and I would like to be able to turn that into:

```
xxx, 12/4/19 10:01, xxx, xxx, 9
```

Here's a piece of R script I've used in the past that will take two tables with lat long and time and tell me what from the second table is close in space and time to the first. What is different in this instance is that I want to go off of one table, and remove rows as they match with other rows before them in the data.

```
time_window = 72 # hours
dist_window = .3048 # km

incidents_list = list()

for (i in 1:nrow(Table1)) {
  if (i %% 100 == 0) {
    print(i)
  }
  Table1_incident = Table1[i,]
  incidents_close_in_time = subset(Table2, DATE_TIME >= Table1_incident$DATE_TIME - hours(time_window) 
                             & DATE_TIME <= Table1_incident$DATE_TIME + hours(time_window))
  dist_matrix = spDistsN1(matrix(c(incidents_close_in_time$long, incidents_close_in_time$lat), ncol = 2), 
                          matrix(c(Table1_incident$long, Table1_incident$lat), ncol = 2), 
                          longlat = T)
 incidents_list[[i]] = (incidents_close_in_time$UNIQUE_ID[dist_matrix <= dist_window])
}
names(incidents_list) <- c(Table1$UNIQUE_ID)
Table1_incidents_df <- map_df(incidents_list, ~as.data.frame(.x), .id = "id")
```

Comment: So if three observations are within a 72 hour period you want their counts summed? Do you want it counted for another observation too? e.g. if you have one observation for the 12/4/19, 13/4/19, 14/4/19 the summed count would be 3, but then do you want the counts of 13/4/19 and 14/4/19 summed for 15/4/19 too?  This would be double counting...